# How to get the number of ticklabels in an Excel graph using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Does someone know how to get the number of ticklabels of an axis when they are generated automatically?
I would like something like

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Ticklabels.Count
```

but the "Count" property does not exist.

I am using Excel 2007 and couldn't find the answer on this site or in the integrated help.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The TickLabels are not a collection, unlike most pluralized Objects. See this MSDN docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff841205.aspx I would ask what you are trying to achieve, then try a different approach

Comment: look into MajorUnit, MinorUnit, MinimumScale, and MaximumScale properties of the Axis Object

Comment: @MacroMarc Thank you for your reply. That may be the wrong approach. I am trying to highlight my graph zone according to the grid automatically generated in order to have a bicolor background (and get vertical strips on background). The number of ticklabels would have gave me the number of vertical major units and therefore the "color separator" places.  

  EDIT : Cannot remove first innacurate comment

Comment: I'm not sure if I have any further suggestions. I don't know how to put in vertical strips...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from MacroMarc's comment above - I played around a bit.  Might be something useful?

```
Sub tickCount()

' Working with horizontal axis - xlCategory

With Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory)

    Debug.Print (.MaximumScale - .MinimumScale) / .MajorUnit

End With

End Sub
```

That seems to return/print the number of ticks or intervals, regardless of whether they're auto or manual set.  Perhaps it's possible to massage that into your code...

Not sure about the vertical strips sorry - sounds pretty cool though!  I guess I'd start by adding a second column series, or two - one for each color, put them on the secondary vert axis and go from there - you're probably already at that stage though...

Comment: Hi @Rovsom, thanks a lot for your reply. It works nice ! It returns the number of regions, so (number of ticklabels  - 1 ).  About vertical strips, I tried another solution with transparent shapes placed with .top and . left properties of the plot area, it fit well but if you move the windows or resize it, an offset appears. I'll try your proposal. Again, thanks a lot !